# How to change the colour of an svg image object in Angular

Tags: css, angular, typescript, svg

In my Angular 12 application, I am using an svg image from outside. I need to change the color of that svg using css.

```
<object type="image/svg+xml" data="assets/icons/certificate.svg"></object>
```

I tried setting like ***fill: red*** but it didn't work.

I need to do it using css because I have setup my app with dark mode too. Otherwise, I could change the fill value of the paths in the source svg file.

Comment: why not use two SVG files and pick which one to use based on whether it's dark mode or not. Or alternatively put the media query for dark mode inside the certificate.svg file.

Comment: Or you could set the "fill" property on your svg file to `fill="currentColor"` - this allows you to change the fill color based on the text color (so in CSS: `color: red` would change the fill to red)

Comment: Would your svg be suitable to use as a mask - then you could 'cut out' the icon on a background color.